# On submit form show modal and then press submit form

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal, form-submit

I have coded this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/aewh7pbf/4/).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var quantityUser = $('#quantityUser').val(); // Read the user input
    var quantityW9 = $('#quantityW9').val(); //the number to compare

    if (quantityUser <= quantityW9) {
      this.submit();
    } else {
      $('#alertQuantity').modal('show');
    }
  });

  $('#cfmContinue').click("click", function(e) {
    console.log("submitttt");
    $('#myform').submit();
  });
});
```

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="https://stackoverflow.com/" role="form">
      <div class="col-lg-3 my-2">
        <label for="firstName">Quantity</label>
        <input id="quantityUser" name="quantity" type="text" value="150" class="form-control" />
        <small id="quantityW9" class="form-text text-muted">100</small>
      </div>
      <div class="col-1 my-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" autofocus>Go</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="alertQuantity" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Warning!</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button id="cfmContinue" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On submit form, I make a check . If this check is true, I show a `bootstrap modal` to the user with a message. Then, the user can continue submitting the form, pressing the `Submit` button in the modal.

However, the `$('#myform').submit();` doesn't work and the the form isn't submitted.

Comment: instead of ```this.submit```, say ```return true;```

Comment: @KalpashreeV.Bal Not working since he preventDefault

Comment: @mplungjan thanks for the comment. I have all the code in the jsfiddle link, that I posted in the begging of the question https://jsfiddle.net/aewh7pbf/4/

Comment: @mplungjan you're right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- get the .text() of the compare value
- convert to numbers
- call the DOM submit event to not execute the event handler again

```js
$('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
  var quantityUser = $('#quantityUser').val(); // Read the user input
  var quantityW9 = $('#quantityW9').text();    //the number to compare
  if (+quantityUser > +quantityW9) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#alertQuantity').modal('show');
  }
});

$('#cfmContinue').click("click", function(e) {
  console.log("submitttt");
  $('#myform')[0].submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <form id="myform" method="post" action="https://stackoverflow.com/" role="form">

      <div class="col-lg-3 my-2">
        <label for="firstName">Quantity</label>
        <input id="quantityUser" name="quantity" type="text" value="150" class="form-control" />
        <small id="quantityW9" class="form-text text-muted">100</small>
      </div>

      <div class="col-1 my-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" autofocus>Go</button>
      </div>
    </form>

  </div>


  <div class="modal fade" id="alertQuantity" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Warning!</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Are you sure;</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <button id="cfmContinue" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @yaylitzis No it did not. You need to get the `.text()` of quantityW9 - I updated

Comment: The conversion to number is done by adding the `+`  in the beginning of the variable?

Comment: Yes. And we need to get the .text of the `small` element it does not have a .val()

Comment: Great! Thanks again a lot for the info!

Comment: why it works $('#myform')[0].submit(); instead of $('#myform').submit(); .please advise

Comment: Because you do not want to execute the event handler again

Answer (score 0):

@yaylitzis Actually the issues with your code "considering that onSubmit will be triggered every time the form got submitted" is the condition will never met as even if you confirmed from modal coz quantity user is greater-than quantity w9.

To get this work you need a checker flag so you can use it within your condition, also for quantityW9 need to use .text() instead of val() as its not input tag.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var checkPass = false;

  $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submit form");
    console.log("checkPass: ", checkPass);
    var quantityUser = parseInt($('#quantityUser').val());
    var quantityW9 = parseInt($('#quantityW9').text());
    console.log(quantityUser, quantityW9);

    if (quantityUser <= quantityW9 || checkPass == true) {
     console.log("Success");
     return true;
    } else {
     checkPass = false;
     console.log("Confirmation check");
     $('#alertQuantity').modal('show');
    }
 });

 $('#cfmContinue').click("click", function (e) {
   checkPass = true;
   $('body #myform').submit();
   $('#alertQuantity').modal('hide');
 });         
});
```

Comment: Nah. See my solution. Just use the DOM submit

Comment: @mplungjan already vote it up, but I've experienced some unexpected behaviour using DOM submit thats why i prefer invoke it that way.